# Existing python3 Ordered Dict to JSON object is not keeping its order when converting to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, flask

in need of some help. I have an existing python ordered dict that I am trying to convert into a json object and preserve the same order that was in the python ordered dict. I have the following line `"streamDict = json.loads(streamDict, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)"` that I thought keet the same order, and when I print this out it seems to be in order. However in my HTML file I have the following line under script tags `"var streamDict = {{streamDict|tojson}}"` and when I do console.log I see the order has now been lost. Can someone help me understand how I can keep the order when converting my python dict to json object?

## This is my route

```
@app.route('/performance_reports_detail<string:clickedOid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def performance_reports_detail(clickedOid):

    streamDict = json.dumps([streamDict])
    streamDict = json.loads(streamDict, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    print('streamDict after loads is {}'.format(streamDict))


    return render_template('performance_reports_detail.html', streamDict=streamDict[0])
```

here is the result of the print statement in my route for json.loads seems to have preserved the order. I am expecting baselinePerformance key to stay first.

```
streamDict after loads is [OrderedDict([('baselinePerformance', OrderedDict([('OSPF_IPv4_Stream3', 4222973.5), ('aggregate', 16891885.5), ('OSPF_IPv4_Stream2', 4222973.5), ('OSPF_IPv4_Stream1', 4222964.5), ('OSPF_IPv4_Stream4', 4222974.0)])), ('PickAndChoosePerformance', OrderedDict([('OSPF_IPv4_Stream3', 4222977.0), ('aggregate', 16891911.5), ('OSPF_IPv4_Stream2', 4222977.0), ('OSPF_IPv4_Stream1', 4222981.0), ('OSPF_IPv4_Stream4', 4222976.5)]))])]
```

## this is my HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var streamDict = {{streamDict|tojson}}
    console.log(streamDict);

</script>
```

Here is console.log output from here, Now you can see order has changed.
[image]

Comment: JSON objects are an unordered set of key value pairs. If you want to preserve the order it's better to just use a list.

Comment: I think I am already doing that. in my route I am doing this streamDict = json.dumps([streamDict]) to wrap my ordered dict in a list. Is that what your referring to?  If that is the case it's still not working.

Comment: That's not how lists work - a list will preserve the order of its elements only, so it'll remember that `streamDict` is its first element, but not the order of things inside `streamDict`. Why not just convert `streamDict` into a list of key value pairs - `streamDict = [[k, v] for k, v in streamDict.items()]`